# How to deserialize an abstract inside of an abstract class in MongoDb?

Tags: java, mongodb, deserialization, abstract-class

I'm trying to convert from mongo document to java class an abstract embedded class.

In my dto i am using the `@JsonDeserialize` in the constructor to achieve this like follow:

```
@JsonCreator
public ParentClass(
        @JsonProperty(value = "id", required = true) @Nonnull String id,
        @JsonDeserialize(as = MyEmbedded.class) @Nonnull MyAbstract embedded
) {
    super(id,
....
```

But i don't know how to achieve this from MongoDocument to Java class.

Is there some `@JsonDeserialize` equivalent for mongo?